i want to make cookicutter conditional propmting cookiecutter.json file
i am creating a cookiecutter project for a fastapi project template after demanding for the user if he want to configure the .env file variables : i want to display the prompts switch the users responses if he says yes the rest of the inputs will be chown
{
    "project_slug": "my_fastapi_project",
    "project_name": "My FastApi App",
    "author": "",
    "prefix": "",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "add .env file ":["yes" ,"no"]
   `your text`

    }


I've recently tackled a similar challenge using a pre-prompting hook. This approach ensures that users are prompted only for relevant questions based on their previous answers.
In the meantime, I've developed a temporary workaround that achieves similar functionality using a combination of hooks and Jinja2 extensions. Below is a detailed explanation of the approach.
Project Structure
.
├── cookiecutter.json
├── cookiecutter.pre.json
├── extensions.py
├── hooks
│   ├── pre_gen_project.py
│   └── pre_prompt.py
└── {{cookiecutter.project_slug}}

Explanation:

cookiecutter.json: The main context file for the Cookiecutter template, defining the template's variables and their default values.
cookiecutter.pre.json: An additional context file used for the pre-prompting hook, containing conditional prompts and their conditions.
extensions.py: A Jinja2 extension to process the context and modify keys as needed.
hooks:

pre_gen_project.py: A pre-generation hook that modifies the context before the project generation starts.
pre_prompt.py: A pre-prompting hook that dynamically updates the  cookiecutter.json  based on user inputs and conditions.


{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}: The directory where the generated project files will be placed, named based on the  project_slug  variable.

cookiecutter.json
{
  "project_name": "My Django Project",
  "project_slug": "{{ cookiecutter.project_name.lower()|replace(' ', '_')|replace('-', '_')|replace('.', '_')|trim() }}",
  "_extensions": ["extensions.StemKeysExtension"]
}

Explanation:

project_name: The name of the project, with a default value of "My Django Project".
project_slug: A slugified version of  project_name  to be used as a directory name, transformed to lower case and with special characters replaced.
_extensions: Specifies the Jinja2 extension (StemKeysExtension) to be used during template rendering.

cookiecutter.pre.json
{
  "include_frontend": "n",
  "frontend_framework": ["React", "Vue", "Angular"],
  "frontend_initializer": ["default", "create-react-app", "create-next-app"],
  "use_celery": "n",
  "celery_broker": ["Redis", "RabbitMQ", "SQS"],
  "__prompts__": {
    "celery_broker": {
      "__prompt__": "Select the message broker for Celery task queue:",
      "Redis": "Redis - In-memory data structure store",
      "RabbitMQ": "RabbitMQ - Open source message broker",
      "SQS": "SQS - Amazon Simple Queue Service"
    }
  },
  "__conditions__": {
    "frontend_framework": "{{ cookiecutter.include_frontend != 'n' }}",
    "frontend_initializer": "{{ cookiecutter.frontend_framework == 'React' }}",
    "celery_broker": "{{ cookiecutter.use_celery != 'n' }}"
  }
}

Explanation:

Variables (include_frontend,  frontend_framework,  frontend_initializer,  use_celery,  celery_broker): Define possible user inputs and their default values.
__prompts__: Custom prompts for variables, providing user-friendly descriptions.
__conditions__: Conditions that determine whether a prompt should be shown based on previous answers.

pre_prompt.py
import sys
import json
import functools
from importlib import import_module

from cookiecutter.generate import generate_context
from cookiecutter.prompt import prompt_for_config, render_variable


class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls.instance = cls._instances[cls]
        return cls._instances[cls]


class PromptProcess(metaclass=SingletonMeta):

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.env = None
        self.context = context
        self.conditions = context['cookiecutter'].pop('__conditions__', {})
        self.cookiecutter = {}
        self.ignored_keys = []

    @staticmethod
    def wraps(func_path):
        def decorator(wrapper):
            try:
                module_path, func_name = func_path.rsplit(".", 1)
            except ValueError as e:
                raise ImportError(f"{func_path} doesn't look like a module path")

            try:
                module = sys.modules[module_path]
            except KeyError:
                try:
                    module = import_module(module_path)
                except ImportError as e:
                    raise ImportError(f"Could not import module {module_path}: {e}")

            try:
                function = getattr(module, func_name)
            except AttributeError:
                raise AttributeError(
                    f"Function {func_name} not found in module {module_path}"
                )

            @functools.wraps(function)
            def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
                return wrapper(PromptProcess.instance, function, *args, **kwargs)

            # Replace the original function with the wrapped version
            setattr(module, func_name, wrapped)

            return wrapper

        return decorator

    @wraps('cookiecutter.prompt.render_variable')
    def render_variable(self, func, env, raw, cookiecutter_dict):
        """Initialize the `env` & `cookiecutter` attrs."""
        self.env = env
        self.cookiecutter = cookiecutter_dict
        return func(env, raw, cookiecutter_dict)

    @wraps('cookiecutter.prompt.read_user_choice')
    def read_user_choice(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.apply_read_user_func(func, *args, **kwargs)

    @wraps('cookiecutter.prompt.read_user_yes_no')
    def read_user_yes_no(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.apply_read_user_func(func, *args, **kwargs)

    @wraps('cookiecutter.prompt.read_user_variable')
    def read_user_variable(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.apply_read_user_func(func, *args, **kwargs)

    def prompt_user(self):
        # Get configuration from the user, ignoring keys in ignored_keys
        user_prompts = {
            k: v for k, v in prompt_for_config(self.context).items()
            if k not in self.ignored_keys
        }
        # Return a prefixed prompts
        return {f"_pre_prompt_{k}": v for k, v in user_prompts.items()}

    def apply_read_user_func(self, func, key, *args, **kwargs):
        if key in self.conditions:
            condition = self.conditions[key]
            try:
                is_met = eval(render_variable(self.env, condition, self.cookiecutter))
            except SyntaxError:
                is_met = False
            if not is_met:
                self.ignored_keys.append(key)
                return None
        return func(key, *args, **kwargs)


def main():
    initial = generate_context()
    context = generate_context(context_file='cookiecutter.pre.json')
    prompt_process = PromptProcess(context)
    initial['cookiecutter'].update(prompt_process.prompt_user())

    # Write the updated context back to cookiecutter.json
    with open('cookiecutter.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(initial['cookiecutter'], f, indent=2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Explanation:

Imports: Necessary modules for context generation and prompting.
SingletonMeta: A metaclass to ensure  PromptProcess  is a singleton.
PromptProcess:

Initialization: Initializes the context and conditions.
Decorators (wraps): Wraps Cookiecutter functions to inject custom behavior.
render_variable,  read_user_choice,  read_user_yes_no,  read_user_variable: Functions to handle the user input and apply conditions.
prompt_user: Prompts the user based on conditions and updates the context with prefixed keys.
apply_read_user_func: Applies conditions to determine if a question should be asked.


main: Generates initial context, processes user prompts, and updates  cookiecutter.json.

extensions.py
from jinja2.ext import Extension


class StemKeysExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, environment):
        super().__init__(environment)
        environment.filters['stem_keys'] = self.stem_keys

    def stem_keys(self, cookiecutter):
        for key in list(cookiecutter.keys()):
            if key.startswith('_pre_prompt_'):
                cookiecutter[key[len('_pre_prompt_'):]] = cookiecutter.pop(key)
        return cookiecutter

Explanation:

StemKeysExtension: A Jinja2 extension to remove the  _pre_prompt_  prefix from keys in the context.

stem_keys: The filter function to process keys and remove the prefix.



pre_gen_project.py
"""
{{ cookiecutter | stem_keys }}
"""

# Check the cleaned context.
print("""{{ cookiecutter | jsonify }}""")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass

Explanation:

Docstring: A Jinja2 template block to apply the  stem_keys  filter to the  cookiecutter  context.
print  statement: Outputs the cleaned context for debugging purposes.
if __name__ == "__main__":: Ensures the script can be run as a standalone module.

Conclusion
This temporary solution demonstrates how conditional prompting can be achieved using existing hooks and extensions.
